# Upload files from Android to server with socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am working on the Android app. I searched a lot posts before create this question. I would like to use socket in java to upload files from android phone. What kind of app should it be in server side? Supposing write the server side in java.What kind of project should it be?
about java application, I only know the server host -- tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case (as server has tomcat) If you have url of the server then you can use HttpURLConnection to upload any file to server. and in server end logic should be written to receive the file
**Example**

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
DataInputStream inputStream = null;

String pathToOurFile = "/sdcard/file_to_send.mp3"; //complete path of file from your android device
String urlServer = "http://192.168.10.1/handle_upload.do";// complete path of server
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

try
{
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

URL url = new URL(urlServer);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Allow Inputs & Outputs
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);

// Enable POST method
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// Read file
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

while (bytesRead > 0)
{
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

// Responses from the server (code and message)
serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

fileInputStream.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Exception handling
}
```

Comment: +1 excellent post, perhaps a brief summary of what kind of code one might expect server-side to match with this would be useful to me.

Comment: Sunil, By your solution, does it mean that I need to creat a webservice or website to recieve the file?  Is there a way to get files from Client with no code in server side? Like FTP?

Comment: Check SPK's link for FTP uploads. It links to a premade FTP class to do the uploading for you. But keep in mind, that using a standard FTP upload might be insecure (as anyone could steal the login data and abuse the server!).